# Failing to store File In Combobox and Read the Data, Size in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am a C++ developer and recently started working on C# WPF app. I am following MVVM. Well I am working on Combobox and buttons. Basically I have a browse button to load a binfile and store it in combobox and when I click TEST button, i should read the data present in file, get the size of it.

**Here is the XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="ClockYHZBox" >              
          <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding FirmwarePath}" />
</ComboBox>
<Button Content="Browse" Command="{Binding WriteFilePathCommand}" Name="RunPCMPDM0" />

<Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding WriteDataTestCommand}" />
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
private string _selectedFirmware;
    public string FirmwarePath
    {
        get; set;
    }

// This method gets called when BROWSE Button is pressed
private void ExecuteWriteFileDialog()
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { InitialDirectory = _defaultPath };
        dialog.DefaultExt = ".bin";
        dialog.Filter = "BIN Files (*.bin)|*.bin";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        FirmwarePath = dialog.FileName; // Firmware path has the path           
    }       

// Method gets called when TEST Button is Pressed
public void mSleepTestCommandExecuted()
    {
        int cmd = (22 << 8) | 0x06; 
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(FirmwarePath);

        string textdata = sr.ReadToEnd();
        int fileSize = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(FirmwarePath).Length;

        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[256];            

        // This gives me the size and data, But i am failing to do
        // further operation of storing value in BUFFER
        // and MEMCPY which is shown below in C++ Code          
    }
```

This is how I had done in my C++ application:

```
MemoryBlock binFile;
m_wdbFile->getCurrentFile().loadFileAsData(binFile); //m_wbdFile is a filedialog object
BYTE *buffer = NULL;
int  fileSize = binFile.getSize();
buffer = (BYTE *)calloc(sizeof(BYTE), fileSize + 2);    
memcpy(buffer+2, binFile.getData(), fileSize);
```

As you can see above, it opens the file, stores the size in `fileSize`, allocates block of memory to buffer and so on. How can I achieve it? I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] b;
FileStream fileStream=new FileStream(FirmwarePath,FileMode.Open);
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
   b = br.ReadBytes(fileSize);
}
```

Comment: I don think `Open` is what Is expected to be the second parameter.

Comment: Your going to want a byte[] instead of the single byte.

Comment: The byte[] can be iterated and manipulated byte by byte.  Your posted code just copies it into the buffer above.  You'll have to post more:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18916/discussion-between-tillerstarr-and-steven-wilson)